# Problemas conexion firebird con base datos .ib(Interbase)

Tags: base-de-datos, delphi, firebird

tengo un problema y es que no puedo conectarme con mi base de datos .IB (Interbase) con firebird.

El caso es que me he bajado el firebird 3.0 y no se como conectarme a la base de datos de interbase que tengo.

¿Necesito algún software mas?

Normalmente en mi configuración anterior tenia el Interbase server y usaba el Ibconsole para el tema de las tablas y demás.

¿Hay alguna forma de realizarlo esto con firebird?

Comment: Aún cuando provienen de un mismo fuente, que divergió hace ya mucho tiempo, Interbase y Firebird son productos diferentes y no ofrecen compatibilidad entre uno y otro.

Firebird 1 tenía la capacidad de restaurar un Backup de Interbase 6, y probablemente mantenga cierto grado de compatibilidad con este, pero nunca ofreció la capacidad de _abrir_ una base de datos de Interbase directamente con el motor de Firebird, y aunque no soy usuario de Interbase, nunca he escuchado que este ofrezca algo similar.

Puedes quizás recurrir a alguna herramienta que mueva los datos entre uno y otro.

Comment: Por otro lado, hasta ahora nunca he escuchado que en Firebird se pueda levantar un backup de Interbase superior a 6, puesto que ya sus estructuras internas, supongo, serán diferentes.

Comment: Que tipo de herramienta podría usar para probar?Estoy un poco perdido con el tema. @jachguate

Comment: No es algo que haya hecho recientemente, pero podrías intentar con [IBDataPump](http://clevercomponents.com/downloads/datapump/index.asp).